# There's no screensaver that shows one picture after the other (as in windows)?

Tags: screensaver, xscreensaver

I want to use a bunch of photos as screensaver.

I haven't found any screensaver that just prints out at the screen each photo, one after the other.

The closest thing that I'm using is the "carousel", but it's not what I want: I just need each picture to show still one after the other, using the fullscreen. I'm using xscreensaver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Select the GLSlideshow screensaver in xscreensaver, open the Advanced tab and under Image Manipulation select "Choose Random Image" and choose the photo directory.

You may need to install xscreensaver again with these extras if the opition isn't available.

`sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl-extra`

Answer (score 0):

If there are no "Advanced tabs" option try this:

open the terminal und type:

```
xscreensaver-demo
```